# Node.js and Redis Auth

Tags: node.js, redis

I dont get the redis node.js documentation for using redis auth.

per the example:

```
var redis = require("redis"),
client = redis.createClient();

// This command is magical. Client stashes the password and will issue on every connect.
client.auth("somepass");
```

In my code I have the following:

```
var redis = require("redis");
r = redis.createClient(6379,'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
r.auth("yyyyyyyy");

app.get('/', function(req, res){
r.set("foo", 'bar');
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif'});
res.end('Hello');
 });
```

Here is the error I get:

```
    Express server listening on port 8070 in development mode

/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/node_modules/redis/index.js:468
                throw callback_err;
                      ^
Error: Auth error: Error: ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set
    at Command.callback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/node_modules/redis/index.js:163:43)
    at RedisClient.return_error (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/node_modules/redis/index.js:464:25)
    at HiredisReplyParser.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/node_modules/redis/index.js:253:14)
    at HiredisReplyParser.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at HiredisReplyParser.execute (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/hiredis.js:41:18)
    at RedisClient.on_data (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/node_modules/redis/index.js:440:27)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbNodejsServer/node_modules/redis/index.js:70:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:367:14)
[7]+  Killed                  node app.js 8070
```

So, what is the proper way to auth?

Comment: EADDRINUSE is an http thing - are you sure this is a problem with redis an not with setting up your server?

Comment: I had the same problem, I found out I had edited the configuration on another server to require a password and the server I was running on my staging server didn't have the `requirepass $uP3rs3cretpassW0rd` in it...  lame! but everything works now.

Answer (score 5):

Also another reason for this problem might be not specifying your redis.conf when starting redis-server (if you put "requirepass" in it).

In that case redis server starts with default configuration (i.e. without "requirepass" option enabled) and therefore doesn't accept your AUTH command.

```
./src/redis-server redis.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code creates a connection to Redis using node package redis.

```
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient({
    host: '<hostname>',
    port: <port>,
    password: '<password>'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to use auth.

I believe you are trying to use an old version of Redis server whose protocol is not supported by node_redis (or vice versa).

Alternatively, you might not connect to the instance you think is password protected, or you have not set a password in the configuration of the instance you target.

I suggest you try to connect to the instance using redis-cli and use auth to test authentication (i.e. bypassing node.js).

Comment: Hi, I am using redis2.6.  I also use py-redis that works with auth.  Auth is working for every other client expect for node.js redis mranney.  Even tornadoredis works.

Comment: It works fine for me. What are your versions of node.js and associated modules (i.e. npm list)? Mine is v0.6.16 with redis@0.7.2 and hiredis@0.1.14 ...

Comment: Node is v0.6.18.  redis is redis@0.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Redis in newer versions enables protected mode by default accepting only loopback and unix domain sockets.

To connect from extern either bind in redis.conf to `bind publicip anotherip etc`
 and `requirepass foobared`. Now test with `redis-cli ping`.
If no `requirepass` anyone can `FLUSHALL` :)

Enable firewall to filter port access for further protection, also see [quickstart security notes.](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart)

Instead of exposing ports you can use (temporarily) ssh tunnels:
Since i wanted a simple and encrypted tunnel, run on client side:

```
 ssh -f -N -L 6379:127.0.0.1:6379 user@<serverip>
```

before starting `node index.js`, so redis is save on its loopback address server-side and i use port forwarding on the client (-f -N for background process ps -x) with setup ssh keys.
If persistent you should look into recommended [spiped](https://redis.io/topics/encryption).

Answer (score 0):

I found someone else with the same problem looking under the redis auth documentation

http://redis.io/commands/auth

You might want to follow up from there

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you and I are having the same problem. I managed to fix mine here, by passing the redis module itself as an option to the RedisStore constructor:

[Redis auth error with Node.js and socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438613/redis-auth-error-with-node-js-and-socket-io)

Without it, the RedisStore module won't recognize the RedisClient objects you're passing in as "true" RedisClient objects (because they'll be a redis.RedisClient class from a *different* redis), and RedisStore will recreate them and lose the auth you set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the password from redis.conf
path (Ex):

```
usr/local/etc/redis.conf
```

Named as =>  **requirepass**

Then you can add it by:

```
const rediClient = redis.createClient({
    password: '<YourPassword>'
});
```

And if you want to auth by terminal you can use:

```
AUTH <password>
```

Ref: https://redis.io/commands/auth/