# Does socket.io RedisStore work on heroku?

Tags: heroku, redis, socket.io, node-redis

I can't seem to get socket.io RedisStore to work on heroku. I'm able to connect to RedisToGo, but when I call `new RedisStore()` I get errors I would expect to get if I hadn't provided the password to the RedisToGo connection such as: `Error: Ready check failed: ERR operation not permitted`

My Configuration:

```
var http = require('http')
  , sio = require('socket.io')
  , _ = require('lodash')
  , port = process.env.PORT || 8000
  , httpServer = http.createServer().listen(port)
  , io = sio.listen(httpServer)
  , RedisStore = sio.RedisStore
  , organization = require('./controllers/organization')
  , chat = require('./controllers/chat')
  , group = require('./controllers/group')
  , util = require('util');

var DEV = false;

if (DEV) {
  var pub = require('redis').createClient()
    , sub = require('redis').createClient()
    , client = require('redis').createClient();
}
else {
  var rtg = require("url").parse(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL);
  var pub = require("redis").createClient(rtg.port, rtg.hostname);
  pub.auth(rtg.auth.split(":")[1], function(err) { console.log('pub ERR: ' + util.inspect(err)); });


  var sub = require("redis").createClient(rtg.port, rtg.hostname);
  sub.auth(rtg.auth.split(":")[1], function(err) { console.log('sub ERR: ' + util.inspect(err)); });

  var client = require("redis").createClient(rtg.port, rtg.hostname);
  client.auth(rtg.auth.split(":")[1], function(err) { console.log('client ERR: ' + util.inspect(err)); });

}


io.configure(function() {
  //create redis connection, set options

  var opts = {host: '127.0.0.1', port: '6379'}
     /******* PROBLEM HERE ******/
    , redisStore = new RedisStore({redisPub: pub,
                                   redisSub: sub,
                                   redisClient: client});


  //io.set('store', redisStore);
  io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
  //io.set('close timeout', 30);
  //io.set('hearbeat timeout', 28);
  //io.set('hearbeat interval', 15);
  io.set("polling duration", 10);
  //io.set('log level', 0);


  if (DEV) {
    require('./lib/dev_static').static(io);
  }
  else {
    require('./lib/prod_static').static(io);
  }

});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  etc ...

});
```

Error Log From Heroku:

`2013-04-30T19:38:30.070457+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 'node app.js'
2013-04-30T19:38:30.917568+00:00 app[web.1]: info: socket.io started
2013-04-30T19:38:31.002714+00:00 app[web.1]: client ERR: null
2013-04-30T19:38:31.009598+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-30T19:38:31.010050+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:506
2013-04-30T19:38:31.003255+00:00 app[web.1]: pub ERR: null
2013-04-30T19:38:31.001801+00:00 app[web.1]: sub ERR: null
2013-04-30T19:38:31.010729+00:00 app[web.1]:                 throw callback_err;
2013-04-30T19:38:31.011043+00:00 app[web.1]:                       ^
2013-04-30T19:38:31.015164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Command.callback (/app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:367:14)
2013-04-30T19:38:31.015164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisClient.return_error (/app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:502:25)
2013-04-30T19:38:31.015164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisClient.on_info_cmd (/app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:319:35)
2013-04-30T19:38:31.015164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisReplyParser.send_error (/app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:266:14)
2013-04-30T19:38:31.015164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:79:14)
2013-04-30T19:38:31.015164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisClient.on_data (/app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:478:27)
2013-04-30T19:38:31.015164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisReplyParser.execute (/app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:125:22)
2013-04-30T19:38:31.015164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisReplyParser.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:262:14)
2013-04-30T19:38:31.015164+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Ready check failed: ERR operation not permitted
2013-04-30T19:38:31.015476+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
2013-04-30T19:38:31.015164+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisReplyParser.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
2013-04-30T19:38:32.242663+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2013-04-30T19:38:32.257231+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`

Answer (score 0):

I was not passing the redis instance into RedisStore along with the clients.

See: [Redis auth error with Node.js and socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438613/redis-auth-error-with-node-js-and-socket-io)